# Mac Pro (Desktop) missing NTFS SATA Drive in VMware Fusion Boot Camp

Tags: bootcamp, windows, vmware, ntfs

Background:
I have a Mac Pro early-2008 DESKTOP :) with 3 HDD installed:

- 1 SATA OSX journaled HDD
- 1 SATA SSD partitioned with my OSX and Bootcamp for Windows 10
- 1 SATA NTFS formatted drive for use with Bootcamp, installing programs and storing data

I have one hard drive that's NTFS and Boot Camp installed on an SSD that I share with my OS X installation. I'd like to be able to boot in to my VMware virtualized Boot Camp partition and access any files or programs I have saved onto my D drive, but it doesn't show. I tried to [create the VMDK](https://kb.vmware.com/kb/2097401), by hand, and added it to Boot Camp VM, but it doesn't seem to show up?

Right now, I can only see that drive if I boot directly in to Boot Camp natively. Is there any way to see my NTFS drive from within VMware Fusion?

Comment: correct, I tried that method. Still doesn't work. Maybe cause it's a bootcamp partition being used as a virtual machine

Comment: sorry, let me be more specific in my answer. I have an actual desktop (Mac Pro) with multiple hard drives connected via Sata

Comment: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/337466?start=15&tstart=0 and http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/faq/#toggle6873  seems it's not possible?

Comment: Tuxera: OS X 10.7 and 10.8: Mac OS X Lion includes a new SMB/CIFS server called smbx. Unfortunately this closed-source replacement for Samba doesn’t allow any other volumes than HFS+ volumes to be shared ..... **this issue has been fixed in OS X 10.9 onwards**. I'm gonna test it as soon as I have found a spare drive.

Comment: you really think it's just an NTFS Driver problem? I actually also tried to manually unmount that volume, but seems still the same... I was hoping that if OSX gave up control, then Windows can finally recognize it.

Comment: Another thing I'm thinking about is could it be because of the partition i use on the drive? I think it may be using EFI, maybe should change to MBR?

Comment: No, no,it's a not EFI vs. MBR. MBR vs GUID partition table would fit. But since the NTFS internal disk is no boot volume it's irrelevant. Sharing works with TCP/IP and both (VMware or OS X) work with SMB/CIFS (afaik). So the only problem would be to read the NTFS file system on the OS X side (and the possibility to share it which wasn't given in Lion/Mountain Lion.

Comment: Okay, I"m currently using El Capitain... so it should still be fine if I add in the NTFS driver, right? hmm... have you had a chance to give it a try? I suppose I can also try later tonight or this weekend if you cannot.

Comment: I get a new spare drive today and I will try it...

Comment: Hi, did you happen to have a chance to give it a go?

Comment: It was DOA drive, so I have to wait until I get a replacement...

Comment: any word on the drive? Sorry to keep asking, but I have a trial I'm using for vmware fusion. i don't want to pay for it if it doesn't work, so i'm eagerly awaiting your reply. :)

Comment: @klanomath did you manage to get to this yet? :)